# Android Studio Beta "Cannot resolve symbol" for all the resources

Tags: android, android-studio

I have upgraded to Android Studio Beta (0.8.0) version from earlier 0.6.x version. After upgrade all the projects (which were working earlier) throws error "Cannot resolve symbol" for everything - String, Activity, file, view - everything. I have done a clean and rebuild;

Obviously I have missed something in the upgrade; What could that be?

And my settings.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
}


apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.grabdata.gdlea.apps"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
       'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use
  this dependency.
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use 
  this dependency.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
 }
```

Comment: Yes. In the project .iml file I had to make one minor change and worked for me: I changed the Android API 19 Platform (2) to Android API 19 Platform (3) and it worked for me. I had to do this in all my others projects which had the same problem.

Comment: I had this same problem, and was finally able to solve it by downgrading the compileSdkVersion from 19 to 17. It may be related to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67823

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and everything worked again.